# Trying to join 2 Firestore documents but page freezes

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to join 2 Firestore documents with eachother. I could not really figure out what the proper method was, so I figured something out myself. This is the function:

```
  function getRooms() {
    setLoading(true);
    roomdb.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const items = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        items.push(doc.data());
      });

      setRooms(items);

      db.collection("Users")
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .collection("Lijstjes")
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const items = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            items.push(doc.data());
          });
          setUserRoomId(items);
        });

      for (var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < userRoomId.length; i++) {
          if (rooms[i]?.id === userRoomId[y]?.id) {
            setUserRooms(...userRooms, rooms[i]);
          }
        }
      }

      setLoading(false);
    });
  }
```

So what I am basically trying to do here is to only show the rooms that the user has in his document. I loop over all the rooms and in that loop I have another loop to see if the room id is the same one that the user has. What am I doing wrong here?

For reference, here is how I structured my data:

Rooms:
[image: Room doc]

Users:
[image: Users doc]

'Lijstjes' means rooms in my language.

I load this function using the useEffect() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your app requires live update of the user's rooms, I don't think this is the correct place for an [`onSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), let alone a nested `onSnapshot`!

You can `get()` a user's rooms given their `uid` with a [simple query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query), then use those returned room IDs to get the room data in another query.

```js
async function getRooms() { // get() queries are async...
  // ...so you need to *await* for the following queries
  setLoading(true)
  return await db.collection("Users") 
    .doc(user?.uid)
     .collection("Lijstjes")
     .get() // returns a an array of user's rooms as DocumentReferences
     .then(function (querySnapshot) {
        const roomPromises = [] // the array where you'll store the .get() requests for rooms
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(docRef) {
            roomPromises.push(db.collection("rooms").doc(docRef.id).get())
        });
        return Promise.all(roomPromises) // execution of each room's .get()
      })
      .then(function (rooms) {
        const roomsData = rooms.map(function (room) { return room.data() })
        setUserRooms(roomsData)
      })
      .then(function () {
         setLoading(false);
       })
    }
```

The basic flow is:

0. setLoading to true
1. get() the [document references](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) in the user's `Lijstjes` subcollection
2. use those document reference IDs to run get() queries for those specific documents in the `rooms` collection
3. return the room documents' data (in this case `setUserRooms`)
4. once you have the data you need (after all asynchronous functions have completed successfully) *then* you can setLoading to false

N.B. the [`Promise.all()` pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is just a way of running the X number of room get() requests in parallel and is a really great practice for speeding up your async functions. That block could also be run sequentially.

Comment: Couldn't have wished for a better answer! Thank you so much for your detailed answer! This definitely helped me understand getting data more. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Graag gedaan, geen probleem! Best of luck with your project! The Firestore docs are your friend. The developer console of your browser is also your friend.